# Naming a class that controls another class

Tags: oop, architecture

I have classes using the strategy pattern (each class has the same single method, but implements it very differently).  I have another class which chooses the implementation to use based on runtime-accessible values.  I have one final class which basically pulls the others together, calls the necessary methods of the implementing class and formats the output.

What could I name this controller class to make it at least semi-clear what it is for?  Before someone asks, it is already a very small class (< 100 lines), not worth splitting - I'm confident that it's not because of multiple responsibilities that I'm having trouble naming it.

I want to say "controller" - but that's already a specific concept in MVC architecture (which our app is using).  Any ideas?  Is there an accepted name for the pattern I'm describing?

Comment: SomethingManager, SomethingOrchestrator, SomethingProvider (probably not), SomethingExecutive...

Comment: If there's no better candidates, I'll be forced to go with *Manager, but I was hoping to avoid that...

Answer (score 1):

In OOP, classes should generally be named after **what they are**; class names should be nouns. You already know that.

The problem with class names like `XyzManager` or `XyzController` is that although technically they are nouns, they're really verbs disguised as nouns. Thus, such classes are named after **what they do**, instead of *what they are*. That makes them not objects, but services, or functions.

Now, **naming is hard**, and sometimes it can't be avoided with an `XyzManager`. Often, when it happens, it's because you've not yet realised what concept the class *really* should encapsulate. Still, you should strive to identify what the class *is*, instead of what it *does*, and name it after that.

FWIW, I often use a thesaurus (there are several excellent online services for that) to find a good name.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to name it **Service**

Example: if you have a TaxStrategyGerman, TaxStrategyFrench that are chosen by  TaxStrategyFactory and used by TaxCalculationService.